# integrity constraint violation when persisting entity

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have some JPA similar to this one, but when I try to persist an employee with proyects I get:

- ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated (EMPLOYEEPROYECTS_FK1) -
  parent key not found.
- ORA-00001: unique constraint (PROYECTS_UK1) violated.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public funal class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEES_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="EMPLOYEES_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator("EMPLOYEES_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    private String field1;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date field2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EmployeeProyect> employeeProyects;

    // bla bla
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PROYECTS")
public funal class Proyect {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PROYECTS_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="PROYECTS_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator("PROYECTS_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    private String field1;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date field2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="proyect")
    private Set<EmployeeProyect> employeeProyects;

    // bla bla
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEEPROYECTS")
public final class EmployeeProyect  {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeProyectPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idEmployee")
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_EMPLOYEE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idProyect")
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PROYECT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Proyect proyect;

    private string commonField;

    // bla bla
}

@Embeddable
public final class EmployeeProyectPK {

    @Column(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
    private long idEmployee;

    @Column(name="ID_PROYECT")
    private long idProyect;

    // bla bla
}
```

Comment: Please add your create table syntax.

Comment: First persist emplyee, then persist project.

Comment: @Antoniossss so you can't persist both at the same time?

Comment: If you can use JPA 2.0 you can change your EmployeeProyect so that you put the ID on your reference mappings, or use @mapsid annotation and JPA will set both foreign keys in it for you automatically, without needing to persist the entities separately.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`: no one can tell you what is wrong because you don't show us how you're initializing your entities and persisting them.